# Closed and bounded intervals of definably complete ordered groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, model-theory, topological-groups, definability, ordered-groups

True or false?

> All closed and bounded intervals of definably complete
>   ordered groups are definably compact.

Let $G$ be an ordered abelian group. Then, a definable subset $D ⊆ G$ is said to be definably compact if for every definable open cover $\{ϕ(a, G)\}_{a∈G}$ of $D$, there exists a pseudo-finite sub-cover $\{ϕ(a, G)\}_{a∈P}$ for some pseudo-finite set $P = ψ(t_0, G)$.

Comment: I think it’d be clearer to say:  “...there exists a sub-cover $\{\phi(a,G)\}_{a\in P}$ indexed by a definable closed bounded and discrete set $P$”.  (Alternatively, if I’m not understanding pseudo-finiteness correctly, that’s worth clarifying in the question!)